# Building a project in TypeScript PureMVC

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, gruntjs, puremvc

My current project is creating a PureMVC project in TypeScript using npm and grunt.  Unfortunately, PureMVC had discontinued their development on their project.  There is barely any PureMVC resources about TypeScript on the Internet.  On their documentation https://github.com/PureMVC/puremvc-typescript-standard-framework/wiki, there is only instructions for setting up a project in Apache Ant.

I would like to create a TypeScript Project with PureMVC by npm and grunt.  Should I use `require.js` to include the PureMVC, or I can include it on package.json instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just use npm install npmvc --save